# Generar Timestamp con una zona horaria especifica

Tags: javascript

Necesito crear una `timestamp` con una zona horaria especifica, ya estoy recogiendo una hora en formato AM - PM como lo necesito, para eso estoy usando la siguiente instrucción

```
new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: "America/New_York", hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit' });
```

Pero necesito tambien enviar exactamente la misma hora pero en formato `timestamp`, esto por que tengo que eliminar los datos que se envian cada 12 horas, pero estoy teniendo problemas por que al crear un `timestamp` con `Date.now()`, me lo genera pero con una zona horaria distinta.

Como puedo generar el `timestamp` con una zona horaria especifica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías poder obtenerlo con el método `getTime` (dividimos por 1000 para no mostrar en milisegundos) a partir de la fecha obtenida usando el parámetro `locale`. Dejo un ejemplo en el que se observa la diferencia entre zonas horarias.

```js
date = new Date();
console.log(date);
date1 = new Date(date.toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: "America/New_York" }));
timestamp1 = Math.floor(date1.getTime() / 1000);
date2 = new Date(date.toLocaleString("es-ES", { timeZone: "Europe/Paris" }));
timestamp2 = Math.floor(date2.getTime() / 1000);
console.log(date1);
console.log(timestamp1);
console.log(date2);
console.log(timestamp2);
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto, gracias hermano.

Comment: Para eso estamos ;)